# Snowflake External Table with Data Share?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-sharing

If I share a Snowflake External table via a direct share with some other Snowflake account(maybe in another cloud region), who pays the compute + data transfer cost when the other account queries the shared table?

Answer (score 1):

If you share data (as opposed to replicate it) then there is no data transfer so there is no cost.

Queries run using a virtual warehouse and costs for a warehouse are charged to the account where the warehouse exists